# Is there a way to encode a csv file to UTF-8 in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, utf-8

My code:  `data = pd.read_csv('Downloads/samplefile.csv',low_memory=False, encoding='utf-8')`

I receive the error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 258663: invalid continuation byte

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In ISO8859-1 character 0xd1 is Ñ. Did you try that encode instead?

Comment: @PauloMarques are you suggesting trying encoding = Ñ ?

Comment: This is a decode operation and it seems like this file isn't utf-8 encoded. Since we don't have the data, we can't really say. You could write a quick test that just opens and reads the file with a utf-8 encoding, not using pandas, just a regular open, and see where the fail is. Is this the first non-ascii character in the file? Is it using some other Windows codepage encoding?

Comment: @tdelaney the file completely fails upon open.

Comment: How does it fail? The same encoding error? You could open in binary, read line by line and decode, then you'll know which line is bad. Then post that. It would be a for loop that reads and prints in binary mode, then tries a decode. The last printed line is what you want: `for line in open('Downloads/samplefile.csv', 'rb'):
    print(line) # prints a bytes object
    line.decode('utf-8') # raises error on fail'

Comment: @TeflonMusk, I suggested to use: `data = pd.read_csv('Downloads/samplefile.csv',low_memory=False, encoding='iso8859-1')`

Comment: If the file was generated on Windows, it is more likely `cp1252` (a.k.a. `Windows-1252`).

Comment: @PauloMarques lifesaver, this worked. Thank you. Feel free to answer the question so I can mark as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data file might *NOT* be encoded in UTF-8, because the character 0xd1 is `Ñ` in the encoding ISO8859-1.

So, use the line below:

```
data = pd.read_csv('Downloads/samplefile.csv',low_memory=False, encoding='iso8859-1')
```